# Building a python web scraper function with user defined url and file name

Tags: python, pandas, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I want the user to input the URL and csv name in this scraper.

```
#Dependencies 
from lxml import html
import requests
import pandas as pd 


x =input('https://web.archive.org/web/20170111201527/https://www.yellowpages.com/nashville-tn/air-conditioning-service-repair')

def Scraper(x):
#URL 
    url = x
#Use Requests to retrieve html 
    resp = requests.get(url) 
#Create Tree from Request Response 
    tree = html.fromstring(resp.content) 
#Path to Website Link 
    elements = tree.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id,"lid-")]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]') 
    websites = []
    for element in elements:
        try:
            websites.append("http"+element.attrib['href'].split("http")[2])
        except:
            continue
#Create Pandas Dataframe
webdf= pd.DataFrame(websites,columns =['Links']).drop_duplicates()
print(webdf)

#Export as CSV
y=input()
webdf.to_csv(y+".csv")
```

My output returns "NameError: name 'websites' is not defined" however that is clearly in the code. I even tried adding it as an empty list before the function with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You are not even calling the Scraper function and returning the value, first change the function like

```
#Dependencies 
from lxml import html
import requests
import pandas as pd 


x =input('https://web.archive.org/web/20170111201527/https://www.yellowpages.com/nashville-tn/air-conditioning-service-repair')

def Scraper(x):
#URL 
    url = x
#Use Requests to retrieve html 
    resp = requests.get(url) 
#Create Tree from Request Response 
    tree = html.fromstring(resp.content) 
#Path to Website Link 
    elements = tree.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id,"lid-")]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]') 
    websites = []
    for element in elements:
        try:
            websites.append("http"+element.attrib['href'].split("http")[2])
        except:
            continue
   return websites
```

And call like

```
websites = Scraper(x)
webdf = pd.DataFrame(websites,columns =['Links']).drop_duplicates()
print(webdf)

#Export as CSV
y=input()
webdf.to_csv(y+".csv")
```